# load custom class in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5, autoload

I am using [yasirsiddiqui/php-google-cloud-print](https://github.com/yasirsiddiqui/php-google-cloud-print) I am not sure if it is composer compatible.

it is a pretty straightforward codes, so I decided just re-route the file and some

```
require_once(app_path().'/cloud_print/Config.php');
require_once(app_path().'/cloud_print/GoogleCloudPrint.php');
```

but Laravel is looking for class in App\Http\Controllers\GoogleCloudPrint

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\GoogleCloudPrint' not found

if I move the `GoogleCloudPrint.php` file to `App\Http\Controllers\` it tell me I can not declare duplicate class. I am assuming it has to do with composer's autoloading? or name spacing?

note: I have no namespace in GoogleCloudPrint, I did not add to composer json, I just require it as it is downloaded.

Comment: weird. very weird.

Comment: @wogsland any thoughts? I am a noob at this...

Comment: if you're using this in a controller, try putting `use GoogleCloudPrint;` at the top of that file. Its looking for the class in your current namespace

Comment: you are a genius @JeffLambert

Comment: Where's this class located in your project?

Comment: thank @MikeBarwick, but Jeff got it, it is in my Controller, I just need to add `use GoogleCloudPrint`, thanks a lot too.